# How to enable VPS in ARcore or ARkit? Any other option for enabling world scale AR and indoor positioning AR?

Tags: gps, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

Looking for VPS SDK, or world scale AR cloud options. Already explored Sturfee too.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different options but none that can do it well over *really* large areas. Most of the outdoor ones work as well as Sturfee does within prescribed regions.

Indoors, most have restrictions around size and/or issues with changing environments as this is an ongoing research problem. You can try ARWorldMap in iOS or Cloud Anchors in Google, they all have space and time limitations because of the research problems mentioned before. You could also try our very own [PlacenoteSDK](https://www.placenote.com) which helps you get started really quickly with pre-built cloud solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as the much-awaited google indoor maps combined with VPS will work well however they showcased it in 2017 and maybe they will be releasing it soon.

Comment: @AryanVerma this is an ongoing research problem so I don't expect Google to release a public solution anytime soon. Everything works if you keep the lighting and environment completely fixed (which is what Google showed in 2017). Your best bet is to try and fit your user experience in one of the solutions mentioned above, no waiting required! :)